# Find month and day from day count to given day

Tags: swift

how to find month and day from day count from beginning of the year, like if dayCount is 53 , then I want to get output as a 2-22.

Comment: `let date = DateComponents(calendar: Calendar(identifier: .iso8601) , year: 2017, day: 53).date   //  "May 1, 2017, 12:00 AM" ` This is what you need.

Comment: thank you very much, this is exactly what i need..